# How do I calculate statistical mode in SPARQL

Tags: subquery, max, sparql

I am trying to calculate the statistical mode (value that occurs with highest frequency) of a dataset using SPARQL.

I can generate a list of data values and their frequencies like so:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?o) AS ?no) ?o 
WHERE {?s ?p ?o  
FILTER isLiteral(?o)
} 
GROUP BY ?o ORDER by DESC(?no)
```

results like so:

```
| 410 | "yes"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
| 19  | "true"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
| 12  | "Offical"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ...
```

However, I just want the first line of data i.e. the value and frequency of the most common object value in the dataset.

I have tried using MAX like so:

```
SELECT (MAX(?no) AS ?maxNo)
{
SELECT (COUNT(?o) AS ?no) ?o 
WHERE {?s ?p ?o  
FILTER isLiteral(?o)
} 
GROUP BY ?o ORDER by DESC(?no)
}
```

and can get the count back like so:

```
---------
| maxNo |
=========
| 410   |
---------
```

but what I want to get back is both the count of the most frequently occuring data value and what that data value is like so:

```
| 410 | "yes"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
```

I have tried binding ?o in the sub-query and adding ?o to the outer SELECT but both give me syntax errors.

What else can I try?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER`-`LIMIT`, also known as "top n", should get you the answer you are looking for.

```
SELECT (COUNT(?o) AS ?no) ?o 
WHERE { 
   ?s ?p ?o  
   FILTER isLiteral(?o)
} 
GROUP BY ?o 
ORDER by DESC(?no)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Fabulous a very simple solution. Works a treat. Thank you so much Andy. Nothing like a bit of lateral thinking, I was definitely over-complicating that one!